# preg_match pattern matches (php)

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a string, such as
`"<span class="m-product-data-3__price-value" itemprop="price" content="143.28">XYZZZ</span>"`
or
`"<span class="m-product-data-3__price-value" itemprop="price" content="198.22">XYZZZ</span>"`

I want to extract XYZZZ value with `preg_match($pattern, $string, $match)`.
But I want the value to be in `$match(1)`
How to do it ? What pattern to use?

`'<span class=\"m-product-data-3__price-value\" itemprop=\"price\" cont ent=\"(.*)\">(.*?)<'si` - gives me the value in `$match(2)`

Comment: I do not understand your question... Please format your code, and put the real `preg_match` you are using

Comment: The round brackets `()` will cause a capture group.. if you don't want it, don't use it^^

Comment: preg_match("'<span class=\"m-product-data-3__price-value\" itemprop=\"price\" cont ent=\"(.*)\">(.*?)<'si", "<span class="m-product-data-3__price-value" itemprop="price" content="198.22">XYZZZ</span>", $match);


content="198.22" is changing... can be  content="198.22", content="143.28", etc 
I need some mask that preg_match will ignore

Comment: $str1="<span class="m-product-data-3__price-value" itemprop="price" content="198.22">XYZZZ</span>" 
and 
$str2="<span class="m-product-data-3__price-value" itemprop="price" content="143.28">XYZZZ</span>"

I need pattern for preg_match to return match(1) ->XYZZZ

Answer (score 0):

Use `(?:...)` for [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions). So your pattern should be:

```
'<span class=\"m-product-data-3__price-value\" itemprop=\"price\" content=\"(?:.*?)\">(.*?)<'si
```

Or maybe dont use parenthesis at all:

```
'<span class=\"m-product-data-3__price-value\" itemprop=\"price\" content=\".*?\">(.*?)<'si
```